# I don't understand what a Euclidean Topology is

Tags: general-topology, notation

I simply don't. Here is the definition I am looking at, from the free book "Topology Without Tears" and also from my lecture notes.

> $\textbf{Definition. }$A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be open in the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ if it has the property that, for each $x \in S$ there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ such that $x \in (a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Confusing me big time. First, let me make this clear, we are looking at $\mathbb{R}$ and NOT $\mathbb{R}^n$, yes? So then, "a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$" should force $S$ to be "one dimensional". In other words, its elements should be of the form $x \in S$. Not $(x,y) \subseteq S$.

So why should $(a,b)$, namely, pairs, should be an element or a subset of $S$ at all as stated in the last bit of the definition?

Further, why is $x \in (a,b)$? These are PAIRS as opposed to $x$ as simply a singleton, or simply a say a number. It is not a pair. What does it mean that $x \in (a,b)$? How can that happen? This is rumbling the very basis of my understanding of mathematics; should I have made such a statement in my math homework, I thought I would have received an irrefutable "cross" mark.

This notational abuse is extremely uncomfortable to me. I have looked up wikipedia and other online sources for a more digestible definition but all they do is throw me a bunch of unfriendly math symbols. Over.

I don't understand what a Euclidean topology is. Apart from it's some bizarre topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Properties? No idea.

Staring at the incomprehensible definition is just giving me a headache, it would be great i someone would help me out.

Comment: $(a,b)$ means the entire interval of numbers between $a$ and $b$, not just the two numbers.  You'd write that as $\{a,b\}$.  The round brackets mean "open interval"

Comment: What youre missing here is that $(a,b)$ is (as well as being the notation for an ordered pair) the notation for the open interval from $a$ to $b$ (i.e., $\{x:a<x<b\}$).

Comment: If you don't know what Euclidean topology is, well: that definition is exactly defining Euclidean topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a,b)= ]a,b[$ the intervall not the pair in $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1):

$(a,b)$ means the entire interval of numbers between $a$ and $b$, not just the two numbers.  You'd write that as $\{a,b\}$.  The round brackets mean "open interval"